# Plotting Time Values in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot time values vs. column readings by uploading a text file with data that looks like:

```
16:07:24,9.13084E+15
16:07:24,8.46849E+18
16:07:24,5.94966E+22
16:07:24,7.15403E+21
16:07:24,3.72465E+14
16:07:24,8.13681E+15
```

My code looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import csv
import datetime
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook


with open('data1.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        a = datetime.strptime((row[0]), "%H:%M:%S")
        x.append((a))
        y.append(row[1])

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Time vs. Column')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I am getting the error message:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'
```

However, all the other questions on SO concerning this issue use datetime.strptime so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It should be `datetime.datetime.strptime`.

Comment: yes that worked! thank you - didn't realize it was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

The `datetime` module contains a class named `datetime`. `strptime` is a class method of the latter, so you should call `datetime.datetime.strptime`.

Comment: @alli if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.